# Issue with AFrame where setAttribute reset previous proprieties

Tags: three.js, aframe

I registered an AFRAME component called `mycomponent` which simply points the camera towards a target and changes position on click. To do that the component has two [propriety types](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/component.html#property-types) which are `target` and `position`.

I created a [pen](http://codepen.io/deva/pen/QvMeom) where you can see the behaviour.

Now if I call `setAttribute` to update the `position`, it changes position but the `target` propriety is reset to default. Furthermore the entity attribute remains the same. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `setAttribute` is overridden for A-Frame primitives. When calling the method to append a component as attribute to the node which already exists, it overrides the existing component attribute. Thus `target` is reset. Seeing you are using an `AEntity`, you may set an attribute of a component to a certain value.
Check the js docs of the setAttribute method in [aframe/core/a-entity.js](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/core/a-entity.js#L683)

To solve the problem, simply call:

```
let camera = document.getElementById('camera')
  camera.setAttribute('mycomponent', 'position', '-10 0 10')
```

Or...

```
let camera = document.getElementById('camera')
  AFRAME.utils.entity.setComponentProperty(camera, 'mycomponent', 'position', '-10 0 10')
```

...which gives you the option to use (custom) delimiters (default is ".") for the first parameter as wel `AFRAME.utils.entity.setComponentProperty(camera, 'mycomponent.position', '-10 0 10' [, delimiter])`.

** Important to note ANode, which is inherited by AEntity, has a different implementation for the `setAttribute` method.

Comment: `camera.setAttribute('mycomponent', 'position', '-10 0 10')` works. Also camera.setAttribute('mycomponent', { position: '-10 0 10' }) works. I wouldn't  use `AFRAME.utils`, but the explanation you made points out what's the black magic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

That may be a bug if you pass a string form into `.setAttribute`.

Try:

```
el.setAttribute('component', {position: '-10 10 10'});
```

Or:

```
el.setAttribute('component', 'position', '-10 10 10');
```